# Can't put onesignal service worker js files in root in github

Tags: github-pages, onesignal

I have used github-pages to publish my site. I'm trying to use onesignal there. But I can't store the sdk files in the root. I'm getting this console error.

`Installing service worker failed TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://username.github.io/') with script ('https://username.github.io/OneSignalSDKWorker.js?appId=<MY_APP_ID>'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.`

Comment: Do you know the location scope of your files? If you can't put them in the root, where are you putting them? Remember you can change the scope of your SW and let OneSignal be aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

A 404 means the service worker script is not where the SDK thinks it is. Try visiting the URL in your browser (https://username.github.io/OneSignalSDKWorker.js). You should see the script there. If it is not there, you have not successfully hosted the required file.